# Can't update textContent of <span> (that is assigned to a variable) from within the callback

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a simple HTML page

[image]

When I press on buttons "Player 1" and "Player 2", I want changes to reflect on the page. In console scores go up, everything's fine, but why page doesn't update the changed score? (`let p1score` and `let p2score`)

**Here's my code, thanks !**

```
const p1button = document
    .querySelector('#p1')
    .addEventListener('click', scoreUp);
const p2button = document
    .querySelector('#p2')
    .addEventListener('click', scoreUp);

let p2score = document.querySelector('#p2score').textContent;
let p1score = document.querySelector('#p1score').textContent;

function scoreUp(e) {
    if (e.target.textContent === 'Player 1') {
        p1score++;
        console.log(p1score);
    } else {
        p2score++;
        console.log(p2score);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to include your code instead of image, please add your full code.

Comment: p2score and p1score are just references. Adding them won't reflect on page. You need to assign it back. It's not a two-way binding thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `let p1score = document.querySelector('#p1score').textContent;` you are effectively saving the value of the text content, not a *reference* to that value. Thus, `p1score` and `p2score` hold their own unique copies of the values (integers) of the text content.

So, when you increment `p1score` and `p2score` you are only incrementing the values in held by these variables. Thus, once you've incremented your value, you should set the text content to be the incremented value by doing

`pScoreOneElem.textContent = p1score;`

`pScoreTwoElem.textContent = p2score;`

This will effectively update the text content by changing its value to reflect the changes to `p1score` and `p2score`:

```js
const p1button = document
    .querySelector('#p1')
    .addEventListener('click', scoreUp);
const p2button = document
    .querySelector('#p2')
    .addEventListener('click', scoreUp);

let pScoreOneElem = document.querySelector('#p1score');
let pScoreTwoElem = document.querySelector('#p2score');

let p2score = pScoreTwoElem.textContent;
let p1score = pScoreOneElem.textContent;

function scoreUp(e) {
    if (e.target.textContent === 'Player 1') {
        p1score++;
        pScoreOneElem.textContent = p1score;
        console.log(p1score);
    } else {
        p2score++;
        pScoreTwoElem.textContent = p2score;
        console.log(p2score);
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="p1">Player 1</button>
<button id="p2">Player 2</button>

<br />
<div class="player-scores">
  Player 1 Score: <span id="p1score">0</span>
  <br />
  Player 2 Score: <span id="p2score">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a lot of repeated DOM querying. I'd just save references to the two `<span>` elements

Answer (score 1):

`let p2score = document.querySelector('#p2score').textContent` only assigns the value of textContent to the score variable. That value is no longer connected to the element text content property. You must reference the element instead

```
const p1button = document
    .querySelector('#p1')
    .addEventListener('click', scoreUp);
const p2button = document
    .querySelector('#p2')
    .addEventListener('click', scoreUp);

let p1 = document.querySelector('#p1score');
let p2 = document.querySelector('#p2score');
let p1score = p1.textContent;
let p2score = p2.textContent;

function scoreUp(e) {
    if (e.target.textContent === 'Player 1') {
        p1.textContent = p1score++;
        console.log(p1.textContent);
    } else {
        p2.textContent = p2score++;
        console.log(p2.textContent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set scores to **p1score** and **p2score** elements like so :

```
if (e.target.textContent === 'Player 1') {
    p1score++;
    document.querySelector('#p1score').textContent = p1score;
    console.log(p1score);
} else {
    p2score++;
    document.querySelector('#p2score').textContent = p2score;
    console.log(p2score);
}
```